# Javascript Quiz with 4 questions. Radiobuttons + continue button

Tags: javascript, html

I try to make quiz with for example 4 questions (more then one). There is 4 radiobuttons for each question and one continue button (`input type="submit"`). I want that when you click on continue button you will be redirected to some page (success.html) but only when all question were answered correctly. When you make some mistake in questions and click continue button it will reload quiz page.

I have tried to do this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
  <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h3>1. otazka: otazocka</h3>
  <input type="radio" name="otazka1" value="n" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Yes
  <input type="radio" name="otazka1" value="n" onClick="toggle(this)" /> No
  <input type="radio" name="otazka1e" value="y" onClick="toggle(this)" /> spravna
  <input type="radio" name="otazka1" value="n" onClick="toggle(this)" /> asda
  <br />
  <input type="submit" id="continue" value="Continue" onClick=""/>

  <script>
  var continue_button = document.getElementById('continue');              

  function toggle(switchElement) {
        if (switchElement.value == 'y')
                continue_button.setAttribute("onClick", "window.location.href='http://www.google.sk'");
        else
                continue_button.setAttribute("onClick", "window.location.href='http://www.facebook.com'");             
  }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But it works only on one question.

I will be glad for some help.
Thanks.

---

Thanks for answer. But when I choose radiobutton and click on continue it didnt redirect me to any page. So I try this

```
<label><input type="radio" name="otazka1" value="n" /> false</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="otazka1" value="n" /> false</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="otazka1" value="y" /> true</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="otazka1" value="n" /> false</label>
  <input type="submit" id="continue" value="Continue" />
<script>
    var continue_button = document.getElementById('continue');
    continue_button.onclick = function(event) {
        var everything_OK = true;
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
            if (inputs[i].type != "radio")
                continue;
            var should_be = inputs[i].value == "y";
            if (inputs[i].checked != should_be) {
                everything_OK = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (everything_OK) {
            // this is not a good success-page
            continue_button.setAttribute("onClick", "window.location.href='succes.html'");
        } else {
            continue_button.setAttribute("onClick", "window.location.href='pop.html'");
        }
    };
</script>
```

but now I must click to continue button twice. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to loop through all your questions and look whether they are checked correctly when the Continue-button is pressed, instead of changing the full validation state of the form when only one answer was selected. Try this:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="otazka1" value="n" /> Yes</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="otazka1" value="n" /> No</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="otazka1" value="y" /> spravna</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="otazka1" value="n" /> asda</label>

...

<input type="submit" id="continue" value="Continue" />
<script>
    var continue_button = document.getElementById('continue');
    continue_button.onclick = function(event) {
        var everything_OK = true;
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
            if (inputs[i].type != "radio")
                continue;
            var should_be = inputs[i].value == "y";
            if (inputs[i].checked != should_be) {
                everything_OK = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (everything_OK) {
            // this is not a good success-page
            window.location.href = "http://www.facebook.com");
        } else {
            window.location.href = "http://www.google.sk";
        }
    };
</script>
```